# Types of Divorce(Talaq) in Islam?

Tags: sharia, talaq

This is probably a very basic question. But I am getting conflicting results from Google regarding the types of Talaq or divorce in Islam. Could someone explain how many types of Talaq are there in Islam and how are they initiated?

**EDIT**

I am specially bewildered by the following article. The article states that there are three types of Talaq, while the rest of the stuff- including Wikipedia- says that there are two.

[Types of Divorce](http://myummah.co.za/site/2008/04/29/types-of-divorce/)

Answer (score 2):

I only know of two types.

You can give single talaq or triple talaq.

The triple Talaq ends the marriage permentantly and you cannot marry the same woman again until she marries again, consummates the marriage and the marriage ends.

In single Talaq you can get back together;if you have intercourse, the talaq is then annulled.

Single talaq should be given.

Inshallah someone will provide more comprehensive information on this.

Comment: not too sure about second link, however, knowledge of the 2 types of divorce is sufficient, and essential for married people.

Comment: What do you mean by *single talaq should be given*? It sounds as if we have a choice. But thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: if you are giving single talaq then you can get back with her, were as triple talaq you cannot. try to see the wisdom in this.

Comment: It would be nice if you could cite a source to support this answer.

Comment: i don't have a source however this is basic knowledge from Hanafi fiqh and not any different from what is said in the website link.

Answer (score 0):

When person marries someone, he/she has the option to terminate their relation by asking for Divorce.

Divorce just as marriage, can be of many types. The other type that my fellow brother has told you are not of 2 types, they are one!

However generally the terms that are well-known can be categorized under:

### Islamic Way

Just the way, a person marries a girl by having  people to know about their relation. Some witness **are/must be** there! Paper work must be done in order to keep a record and to go for a legal act to let the female get/ask for her rights to her in-laws.

Try taking an example of a newly married girl, she might get a baby soon. If she is divorced, what would you expect her to do? That is why Nikah was signed in between both of the parties (boy and girl). Now she can ask for her Haq Meh'r and other rights, such as food and shelter for her/her in-laws baby etc.

In Islam, a woman completes her iddat in her husbands house (if husband is alive). So that if she has to be pregnant it would be taken a note there.

Even after the divorce, that has taken place such as (husband has said 'I divorce you' three times) there is a trial period for 3 months for husband to retry to maintain their relation. In this period, they can be wife/husband again without any issue.

Also, remember the divorce that took place in aggression is never accepted since that was an emotional divorce and would be not a good decision for both of the families. That is why, the trial period of 3 months has been given to the families.

In our cultures, we people aggressively take our daughters back to our home saying, 'Lets go daughter! These people don't deserve you'. Well if they didn't why you married her to them in the first place?

Also, I would like to beg a differ to other answer. There is no such thing as

> The triple Talaq ends the marriage permentantly and you cannot marry the same woman again until she marries again, consummates the marriage and the marriage ends.

In Islam it is not allowed, this is just a ritual made up by ourself. You will not be able to find any of the example of Halaala (this ritual is known as Halaala; in which a divorced girl is married to someone else and she has to go through sexual intercourse with that guy, and then upon a divorce from him, she can marry the first person again. Huh!). That's why, that answer is not fully supported and is based on a ritual rather than the true teachings of Islam.

### Legal Way

A female or male, can go to court and ask for divorce legally, if she/he has any sort of trouble. Wife can ask for her rights too, like to keep the children in her own custody, to ask for monthly payment by male for her and her children's expenses.

You can learn more about the Legal divorces here:

http://www.divorcenet.com/resources/divorce/the-different-kinds-divorce.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of talaq (divorce):

1. Talaq e muqhallaza (three talaq at a time)

   After this divorce one cannot marry that woman again before she marries another person and get divorce from him.
2. Talaq e rajqh (returnable)

   When a person give just one talaq or two then this is called talaq e rajqhi and that person can come back from his decision of divorce
   ( talaq)and can make the divorced woman his wife by just return(rujoo) there is no need of nikah( marriage contract again) but this return may be by conversation/ shaking hands/ meeting/etc.
3. Talaq e Baina(divorce by such words which meant talaq indirectly not directly).

   Such as one says to his wife go out of mu house or says get loss or says go to your parents etc and means to divorce his wife. If he wishes of the talaq then talaq happens and this is called talaq e baina. The man cannot live with the same wife with out another nikah( marriage contract ) ie if he wants to remain her as wife he must marry with her,( marriage contract).

Answer (score -1):

The types of Divorce ( Talaq ) are Four in other View.                               1) Talaq ( in which by a husband pronounciation ) = In this type of Divorce, it is spell out by A husband to his wife, declaring a Seperation to that particular Social Contract. Once a word of Divorce in this Term is commenced, there's no amendment in which to wipe it as a mistake, even in a Bed of Sick or Intoxicated, either to pronounce a Divorce beyond 3 terms. According to Maliki School of Thought " Such type of Divorce can not be Reconcilled if a person became Intoxicant Voluntarally, and when ever beyond 3 terms, it will be reduced to 1 term of Divorce. According to Hanafi " Such type of Divorce can be reconcilled when a person even Voluntarally became Intoxicant, after He gain the conscious to ask him if He mean such Divorce.                   2) khul'i ( Men are your cloth and you are their cloth ) = Therefore, it is not only A Men that has such right of Divorce at his own will, even Women can be title to Divorce in this type. When ever a woman is no longer interested in being with her Husband, she has the right to complain before the Arbitrators, Such Divorce can be Valid if the Woman can take back the Dowry she recieved by the Man. Such Case Happened During prophet Muhammad's life time.      3) Tafriq ( An allegation in ponder ) = In a nut Shell, when there is an allegation in between a Husband and wife the Divorce may Be consider. For Example, if a husband Reject a pregnant of His wife, claiming that it is not by him, therefore, the Arbitrators are in title to Seperate them, and no Marriage to be Conducted between them again.                        4) ( cant remember the Arabic title ) Islam Issue = in this type, it is when a Husband or Wife cannot focus on Islam. I.e If a husband or wife can not pray, fasting, zakat etc in respect of Five pillars of Islam. One can Complain to the Arbitrators, when Husband or wife set at default to do so, then the Marriage can be Seperated.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).